# RegEx non-greedy quantifier .*? not working as expected

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to create a regex to match "section 2 foo 2019 foo" in the following string (a minimal example, not the real thing):

```
section 1 bar bar section 2 foo 2019 foo section 3 bar 2021 bar end
```

(string "section", followed by a number, followed by any text, followed by a 4-digit year, followed again by any text)

My initial thought was to use non-greedy quantifiers and one capturing and one non-capturing group, like this:

```
(section [0-9]{1}.*?(19|20)[0-9]{2}.*?)(?:section)
```

However, this will produce the following match for the capturing group:

```
section 1 bar section 2 foo 2019 foo
```

So, it also matches section 1, which I want to exclude.

After some background reading, I understand that the problem here is that "non-greedy" does not actually mean "match the shortest possible string", but instead it means "match the shortest possible string reading from left to right without backtracing".

There are a few answers here on SO regarding this problem, but I am still struggling to find the right regex for this particular case. I tried using a non-capturing group with negative lookahead, like this:

```
section [0-9]{1,2}(?:(?!section [0-9]{1}).).*(?!202[1-9]{1})[0-9]{4} .*?
```

But this will still match the first unwanted section, unexpectedly.
Any idea where my thinking might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that using `.*?` for the "any" text part still has the potential to match across sections which either match or do not match, until finding a closing year.  Your final regex which attempts to use a tempered dot is on the right track.  Consider this version:

```regex
\bsection \d+ (?:(?!\bsection \d+).)*?(?:19|20)\d{2}\b
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```
\bsection \d+             match "section" followed by a number and space
(?:(?!\bsection \d+).)*?  match any content, without crossing over to another section
(?:19|20)\d{2}\b          match a 4 digit year
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim, for the quick reply and the detailed answer. This looks great. 
For the record and for anyone who (like me) stumbled over the expression "tempered dot", here is an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat